# matrixProfiling not getting imported

Tags: python, time-series, timeserieschart, matrix-profile

I am trying to use the package 'matrixprofile'.
I am getting the error even though I have installed a 'matrixprofile' in anaconda prompt.

```
from matrixprofile import *
mp = matrixProfile.stomp(df['y'].values, window)
```

> NameError: name 'matrixProfile' is not defined

Other people have been able to use the same code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: This question lacks details. Which matrixprofile are you trying to install exactly, [matrixprofile](https://github.com/matrix-profile-foundation/matrixprofile) or [matrixprofile-ts](https://github.com/target/matrixprofile-ts)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mp = matrixprofile.stomp(df['y'].values, window)
```

Just replace `matrixProfile` with `matrixprofile`.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work, I fixed it. The problem was that from anaconda prompt the command is `pip install matrixprofile-ts` and not `pip install matrixprofile`